# ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace() is not taking the currently opened workspace

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am a novice in Plugin development and I am facing this issue in opening my current workspace:

ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace() is not taking the currently opened workspace which is D:/ABCDWoekspace, instead it is returning the workspace of eclipse that is created in the eclipse installaction directory d:/eclipse/workspace as my eclipse in installed in D:eclipse

Answer (score 1):

When you run your plugin from within Eclipse a new Eclipse is started with a new workspace in which to run the test. A new workspace is necessary because only one Eclipse instance can access a workspace at a time.

If you open 'Run > Run Configurations' and find your plugin in the 'Eclipse Application' section you can see the workspace location in the 'Location' field on the 'Main' tab. You can change this location to point to another existing workspace location.

You will need to set up this new workspace with whatever projects you need for testing.

Comment: let me clarify, I need to run the plugin on a project that belongs to another worspace

Comment: Well change the Run > Run Configuration location to specify the other workspace location.

Comment: thanks, tried to do this..but this did not work, I had to switch my workspace to the default one created and import my projects there with the option Copy to Workspace selected. It was able to find my projects then